# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many on Model.where... (only some Model instances)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Ok, this is a tricky one for me. After at least 5 hours of googling and exerimenting with various metaprogramming techniques I have run out of ideas.

I am trying to add a has_and_belongs_to_many association only to some instances of my User model. Here is the relevant part of the code:

In my User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  after_initialize :setup_trainer

  def setup_trainer
    return true unless trainer?
    self.class.instance_eval {include TrainerMethods}
  end

  module TrainerMethods

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      has_and_belongs_to_many :trainings
    end

  end
  ...
end
```

And then in my Training Model:

```
class Training < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :trainers, class_name: "User"
end
```

This is only one of the several techniques I tried and the issue here is that not just trainers but every User is added the habtm association.

Is there a way I can add the habtm association only to trainers?

UPDATE: 
If I simply add the association to the User model as suggested. both regualar users and trainers that don't have trainings would return [] 
Do you think this is fine and in case we need to clarify what kind of user we are looking at we call the @user.trainer? method?

Thank you very very much.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do this. By adding a normal HABTM association, for any User that is not a trainer, `trainings` would just be empty.

Comment: Also, this would require special handling if ever you want to call `@user.trainings` - if the user is not a trainer, you'd get a NoMethodError.

Comment: @sevenseacat thank you for your comment, to be honest this was not by my design only, I am working on it with a more experienced developer and this was his decision. It kind of makes sense to me since a normal User cannot have a training and it would be fine to raise an error if we, by accident, try to find user.trainings. What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord associations just mean you can (if required) create / build associative data. Associations are not a binding thing - you don't *have* to include data just because you have one set up

---

[**has_many :through**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

If you'd like to associate a number of trainers to users through a mediator model, you might be better doing this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :trainings, foreign_key: "trainer_id", association_foreign_key: "user_id"
    has_many :trainers, class_name: "User", through: :trainings, foreign_key: "trainer_id"
end
```

This will give you a schema like this:

```
users
id | user | details | created_at | updated_at

trainings
id | user_id | trainer_id | created_at | updated_at
```

Both `user_id` & `trainer_id` will reference the `User` model

It will allow you to do this:

```
@user = User.find(id)
@trainers = @user.trainers
```

Comment: Thank you Rich, I do have various associations set up on the User model to represent the multiple relationships of our users between eachother.
Perhaps I am missing the point in the habtm relationship, thank you anyway

Comment: No problem! `HABTM` is much less flexibility than `has_many :through`, primarily because it doesn't use a model. This means if you wanted to self reference another model, it's going to be much harder